# C++ Is there a way to initialize unordered_map using contents of vector as keys and custom values?

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, unordered-map

Let's say I have a vector

```
vector<int> vect;
vect.push_back(2);
vect.push_back(3);
```

Now I want an unordered_map with those 2 and 3 as keys and 0 as default values for all those keys.

Is there a way to do it?

I tried doing

```
unordered_map<int, int> myMap(vect.begin(), vect.end());
```

hoping it would initialize with what's in the vector as keys and default int value.

However, it couldn't.

I mean, I can always just iterate the vector and manually insert pairs.

I just want to know if I can do it as a one liner during declaration.

Comment: I don't think so. One thought is to create a `std::vector` containing `std::pair` values and then use it to initialize the `unordered_map`. But that is probably not what you are looking for. I am interested if there is indeed a way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Actually a simple one liner is enough, but not on declaration:

```
vector<int> vect = { 2, 3, 4};
unordered_map<int,int> map;
transform(vect.begin(), vect.end(), inserter(map, map.end()), [] (int v) { return make_pair(v, 0); });
```

Comment: Simpler would be `for (int i : vect) map[i];`